# objective c - derived UIAlertView OK button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some regular alert views and a custom alert view called 'UINotificationAlertView'
I want the 'ok' button click event on the custom UINotificationAlertView to use the second method and not the first. How can I do this? Im new to objective c so sorry if this is a dumb question.

```
UINotificationAlertView *message = [[UINotificationAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@""
                                    message:row.alertBody
                                    delegate:self.
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"                      
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Both methods in App delgate:

```
//UIAlertView delegate
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

        if(buttonIndex == kNo) {
        } else {
            //Close by suspending...
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] suspend];
        }
    }
    - (void)alertNotificationView:(UINotificationAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        NSLog(@"phils new delegate");
        if(buttonIndex == kNo) {
        } else {
            //Close by suspending...
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] suspend];
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might have to subclass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

In your .h file, enter:

```
@interface YourClassName : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

In your .m file:

`message.delegate = self;`

Comment: i created a blank class to handle the different notifications then in my app delegate just called the method from my new class that did this. the new class used rudys code above.